# Текст справа от input type='radio', как сделать кликабельным?

Tags: html, ui, css, javascript

Прошу прощение за банальный вопрос. Есть "выбор" на построенный на `<input type="radio">` хотелось чтобы активным была не только сама кнопка но и текст справа, вроде есть атрибут `label`, но что-то без эффектов.

Понятно что можно задать каждому `input` свой `id`, и по клику делать `$('radio1').value.checked()` но мб есть и другие более изящные варианты?

Пример кода: http://jsfiddle.net/4YUuP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё очень просто, спасибо за внимание:

```
<label><input type="radio">Label 1</label>
<label><input type="radio">Label 2</label>
<label><input type="radio">Label 3</label>
<label><input type="radio">Label 4</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/AbvLV/2/

```
var oldRadio;
$( document ).on( "change", 'input[name=pos1]', function(event) {
    if(oldRadio)oldRadio.closest('li').removeClass('active');
    oldRadio=$(this);
    oldRadio.closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Можно без переменной, но тогда постоянно нужно будет удалять классы у всех элементов списка.

Comment: Дорогой товарищ, вы сделали что при клике на радио выделяется текст, а мне надо чтобы при клике на текст выделялся радио(становился checked)

Comment: Да, совсем не так понял, уцепился за "эффекты". За label вас спасибо